# Append a list of strings to a file in a single line? - Python

Tags: python, string, file, append, output

Is there a way to append a list of lines to a file in a line of python code? I've been doing it as such:

```
lines = ['this is the foo bar line to append','this is the second line', 'whatever third line']

for l in lines:
  print>>open(infile,'a'), l
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two lines:

```
lines = [ ... ]

with open('sometextfile', 'a') as outfile:
    outfile.write('\n'.join(lines) + '\n')
```

We add the `\n` at the end for a trailing newline.

One line:

```
lines = [ ... ]
open('sometextfile', 'a').write('\n'.join(lines) + '\n')
```

I'd argue for going with the first though.

Comment: seems like this is the closest we'll get to one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that :

```
lines = ['this is the foo bar line to append','this is the second line', 'whatever third line']

with open('file.txt', 'w') as fd:
    fd.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

Comment: @2er0 If you need to append yes (i.e if there's already something in the file), but with this solution, you write the whole buffer at once, so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of re-opening the file for every write, you could

```
lines = ['this is the foo bar line to append','this is the second line', 'whatever third line']

out = open('filename','a')
for l in lines:
  out.write(l)
```

This will write them on a new line each. If you want them on a single line, you can

```
lines = ['this is the foo bar line to append','this is the second line', 'whatever third line']

out = open('filename','a')
for l in lines:
  longline = longline + l
out.write(longline)
```

You might also want to add a space, as in "longline = longline + ' ' + l".